# Swift: Mirror(reflecting: self) too slow?

Tags: ios, swift, mirroring

I am trying to make a dictionary with the properties of a class of mine.

```
class SomeClass() {
    var someString = "Hello, stackoverflow"
    var someInt = 42 // The answer to life, the universe and everything
    var someBool = true

    func objectToDict() -> [String: String] {
        var dict = [String: String]()
        let reflection = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for child in reflection.children {
            if let key = child.label {
            dict[key] = child.value as? AnyObject
        }
        return dict
    }
}
```

but `objectToDict()` is very slow. Is there a way to speed this up, or may be another approach to add the property values to a Dictionary?

Comment: You shouldn't be mirroring except for purposes of reading this value from the debugger, so speed doesn't matter. If you are mirroring for some other purpose, back up and implement this another way.

Comment: @matt , is there any convenient way to "translate" the object to a Dictionary? I need to pass this dict as json to a web service, that's the real purpose.

Comment: If this object were an NSObject derivative, you could ask the Objective-C runtime to introspect it for you. There isn't any convenient way in pure Swift. Personally, I would just write the conversion by hand, one property at a time.

Comment: Also, may I ask why you are passing through that very strange `as? AnyObject` cast? If you want a [String:String], just coerce each `value` directly to a String. I'm surprised your code even compiles (in fact I don't understand why it does).

Comment: In the majority of cases, I've found that just converting to JSON by hand is the best solution. It's really quite simple code in most cases. (See @andyvn22's answer for an example of this; it really isn't that bad in most cases, and doing it by hand makes all the little weird corner cases where your JSON doesn't match your struct 100% much easier to deal with). But for those case where it is not simple, I recommend https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON to help. Mirror is the wrong tool.

Comment: My original code is ```[String: AnyObject]``` , that's why it compiles. And how Obj-C runtime will retrospect this for me? Can you give me an example, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is that slow, it's also not a good idea: **mirroring is for debug introspection only**. You should instead construct the dictionary yourself. This ensures that you have the flexibility to store all the data in exactly the right way, and also decouples your Swift property names from the keys of the dictionary you're generating.

```
class SomeClass {
    var someString = "Hello, stackoverflow"
    var someInt = 42 // The answer to life, the universe and everything
    var someBool = true

    func objectToDict() -> [String: AnyObject] {
        return ["someString": someString, "someInt": someInt, "someBool": someBool]
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872370/  where I have some performance tests using a direct conversion to dictionary vs protocol conformance vs protocol extension with `Mirror`.

Answer (score 7):

I do not agree with most other users. Using reflection results less code, which means less time to develop, maintain, and test your product. With a well written library like `EVReflection` you don't need to worry about things behind the scene too much.

However, if performance is going to be a concern, do *NOT* use reflection based approaches at all. I'd say it's never really a problem in front-end development for me, especially in iOS, but it cannot be ignored in back-end development.

To see how slow it can be, I ran some test in Xcode. I'll write a blog about it, but generally speaking, getting `Mirror` is not the worst part (plus it may be possible to catch property list in memory), so replacing it with objc runtime wouldn't change the situation too much. In the other hand, `setValue(_, forKey)` is surprisingly slow. Considering that in real life you also need to perform tasks like checking `dynamicType` and so on, using the dynamic approach surely will make it 100+ times slower, which won't be acceptable for server development.

```
- Looping 1,000,000 times for a class with 1 `Int` property
  - Getting mirror: 1.52
  - Looping throw mirror and set `child.value`: 3.3
  - Looping throw mirror and set `42`: 3.27
  - Setting value `42`: 0.05
```

Again, for iOS I'll keep using it to save my time. Hopefully end customers won't care about whether it's 0.005 seconds or 0.0005 seconds.