# More efficient way for converting structure properties into dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, reflection

I was looking for most efficient way for creating dictionary from structures. After small research I found easy way for converting it via initialising all properties like that :

```
func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
    let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["firstProperty" : sth, "secondProperty" : "sth2"]
    return dictionary
}
```

But wait.. Do I have to initialise it every time in my structures ? They might have a loot of properties.. It gave me to think. What if I could get properties though the looping of the class somehow. Yeah, it is possible using `Mirror` reflection. After a while of trying I've got it - instead of function above I've written protocol which implements one function.

```
protocol Mirrorable {
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject]
}
```

Then in my structure I can simply use :

```
extension MyStructure/MyClass : Mirrorable {

    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
        let reflection = Mirror(reflecting: self).children
        var dictionary = [String : AnyObject]()
        for (label, value) in reflection {
            dictionary[label!] = value as AnyObject
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}
```

Curiosity does not let me to stop thinking about it. Which way would be more efficient ?

Comment: Do you mean which one is faster?

Comment: @Hamish Yeah, faster and what about performance. Also code in second option looks less dirty than it could be in the first option with more than couple of the properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TLDR

Direct conversion is faster but since most cases you won't have to convert 1.000.000+ structs to dictionary I'd use a protocol extension.

---

## Long answer

I created a Mac cmd line app to test the time and as expected the direct conversion is faster. 
This is kind of obvious since the compiler could optimize it and since the code itself is simple. When using reflection you create a bunch of extra structures and variables, also add some overhead.

Even though the direct conversion is faster, I think in most real cases would be fine to use the protocol extension approach since it's easy to adopt in your code base. One thing you must have in mind is that your code using reflection is not considering nested objects, this would make the method even slower and also if you used recursion would generate a bigger overhead.

Here are the results for 3 executions encoding 1.000.000 structs to a dictionary:

## Build settings

- Apple LLVM 8.1 - Code Generation

  - Optimization Level: -Ofast
- Swift Compiler - Code Generation:

  - Optimization Level: -O -whole-module-optimization

> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.569061994552612
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   7.68360501527786
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   7.71803396940231
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.500779032707214
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   7.58478999137878
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   7.73368299007416
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.492152035236359
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   7.81585901975632
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   7.41855001449585

## Build settings

- Apple LLVM 8.1 - Code Generation

  - Optimization Level: -Ofast
- Swift Compiler - Code Generation:

  - Optimization Level: -Onone

> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.92627400159836
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   9.25952398777008
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   9.19355899095535
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.9830749630928
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   9.06750500202179
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   8.77240401506424
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.81389397382736
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   8.84287703037262
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   9.08754301071167

## Build settings

- Apple LLVM 8.1 - Code Generation

  - Optimization Level: -O0
- Swift Compiler - Code Generation:

  - Optimization Level: -O -whole-module-optimization

> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.533200979232788
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   8.15365797281265
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   7.80043601989746
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.509769976139069
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   7.76911997795105
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   8.00845402479172
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   0.532546997070312
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   7.99552202224731
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   7.86273497343063

## Build settings

- Apple LLVM 8.1 - Code Generation

  - Optimization Level: -O0
- Swift Compiler - Code Generation:

  - Optimization Level: -Onone

> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.90398299694061
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   9.62662398815155
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   9.55038601160049
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.98312002420425
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   9.62088203430176
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   8.82720899581909
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S1(direct conversion):
>   2.77569997310638
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):
>   8.83749902248383
>
> Time for 1000000 executions with S3(protocol extension):
>   8.76373296976089

## Code:

```
import Foundation

// Direct conversion to dictionary
struct S1 {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
        let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "a":a as AnyObject,
            "b":b as AnyObject,
            "c":c as AnyObject
        ]
        return dictionary
    }
}

// Conversion using struct extension + protocol
protocol Mirrorable1 {
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject]
}

struct S2 {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
}

extension S2: Mirrorable1 {
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
        let reflection = Mirror(reflecting: self).children
        var dictionary = [String : AnyObject]()
        for (label, value) in reflection {
            dictionary[label!] = value as AnyObject
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}

// Conversion using protocol extension
protocol Mirrorable2 {
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject]
}

extension Mirrorable2 {
    func toDictionary() -> [String : AnyObject] {
        let reflection = Mirror(reflecting: self).children
        var dictionary = [String : AnyObject]()
        for (label, value) in reflection {
            dictionary[label!] = value as AnyObject
        }
        return dictionary
    }
}

struct S3: Mirrorable2 {
    var a: Int
    var b: Int
    var c: Int
}

let listOfExecutions = [1_000_000, 1_000_000, 1_000_000]
for executions in listOfExecutions {
    // S1
    var start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for i in 0..<executions {
        S1(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2).toDictionary()
    }
    print("Time for \(executions) executions with S1(direct conversion):")
    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)

    // S2
    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for i in 0..<executions {
        S2(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2).toDictionary()
    }
    print("Time for \(executions) executions with S2(struct extension + protocol):")
    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)

    // S3
    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for i in 0..<executions {
        S3(a: 0, b: 1, c: 2).toDictionary()
    }
    print("Time for \(executions) executions with S3(protocol extension):")
    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start)
}
```

Comment: Got ya! The protocol code looks much more familiar. Also I've upgraded a bit code and created extension to the protocol and moved the implementation of the `toDictionary()` as a default implementation. Now I only have to extend protocol without implementing in each struct this method.

Comment: Yep, in general that would be my approach as well! Just remember to consider if you're gonna need to handle nested structs if using reflection. Happy coding :)